# How to exclude a category name from showing?

Tags: wp-query, categories

So I'm trying this code:

```
<?php
global $post;
$my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=8&category_name=featured');

while ($my_query->have_posts()):
    $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
    $category = get_the_category();
    $content = get_the_content();
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) , 'main-thumbs');
    $tn_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($tn_id, 'main-thumbs');
    $width = $img[1];
    $height = $img[2];
?>
....
<div class="cat-square <?php
    echo esc_html($category[0]->slug) ?>">
```

with this, I can style a generic div (cat-square) and then add some additional styling depending on the category the post is in. So far so good, this work as a charm. Exception made that categories, which are all scientific disciplines, can also belong to `Featured` category . So, sometimes the category (let's say *Physics*) is replaced by *Featured* category.

How can prevent this from happening? Please note that I don't mean to exclude the post itself, only the `Featured category` nicename and slug

Comment: Have you tried the `category__not_in` parameter? I haven't tried using `category_name` and `category__not_in` at the same time, but it may work.

Comment: yes, but it excludes the post as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `get_the_category` is returning you an array of objects (see [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/) for more info), so if the post has more than one term assigned, then you are just outputting the first one.

So I think that doing a foreach loop will solve your problem:

```
foreach ($category as $cat) {
    if ($cat->slug != 'featured') {
        echo esc_html($cat->slug);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Capiedge, I can't mark your question as correct because the site doesn't allow me to complete the registration, but I want to thank you and confirm this is the correct solution indeed! (btw, it's me, Ariel, just that this site is the anti-UX site and does everything a site is not supposed to do)

Comment: well, I could do it with another account, lol :D